# General solution to an trigonometric equation set

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

An extent for last question I asked is to solve
$$\begin{cases}
2\cos(2y_1)=1+\cos(y_1+y_2)\\
2\cos(2y_2)=\cos(y_1+y_2)+\cos(y_2+y_3)\\
2\cos(2y_3)=\cos(y_2+y_3)+\cos(y_3+y_4)\\
...\\
2\cos(2y_{n-1})=\cos(y_{n-2}+y_{n-1})+\cos(y_{n-1}+y_n)\\
2\cos(2y_n)=\cos(y_{n-1}+y_n)-1\\
\end{cases}$$ 
Where$$y_1,y_2,...,y_n \in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
It's evident that one solution {$\space y_1,y_2,...,y_n\space$} are supposed to be symmetric with $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but it remains to be observed whether the symmetric solution is the unique one. Besides, even assuming they are symmetric, it's still a big deal to find the close-form expression for each elements.

So, can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You could rewrite the system as $z_{ij}:=\cos(y_i+y_j)$ an then proceed to solve it with gaussian elimination.